# $location.path does not load related page if its promise was earlier rejected during auth interception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am having problems making auth interception work in my AngularJS app.

To illustrate I have made a very simplified version of my app containing a Log In page (path `/login`) and a Hello World page (path `/`) which you have to be logged in to see. The greeting displayed at the Hello World page is fetched via Ajax during a route provider resolve and this will only succeed if a valid access token is provided.

This is what I experience:

1. The user tries to access the Hello World page at `/`.
2. Before the Hello World page controller can be loaded, a greeting text should be fetched from the server – as no access token is yet known, the server responds with `status 401`. This is caught in `responseError` of the auth interceptor from where the user is redirected to the Log In page at `/login`.
3. At the Log In page the user is prompted for credentials until the auth API at the server is happy and returns a valid access token – this access token is stored for later use and the user is redirected to the Hello World page at `/`.
4. **Instead of refetching the greeting text using the newly obtained access token and then display the Hello World page, the Log In page remains visible – the URL in the address bar is updated to mention `/` instead of `/login` though.

   Why is the page related to `/` not loaded? The promise was previously rejected but should it not try to resolve the promise again?

   Or is it just not possible to mix promise stuff with auth interception the way I try to do it here?**

---

Screen shot of the console:

[image: console]

---

Files:

`index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="HelloApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>

  <script src="/test/auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/test/hello.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

---

`auth.html`:

```html
<h2>Please log in</h2>

<form ng-submit="logIn(credentials)">
  Username: <input type="text" ng-model="credentials.username"><br/> Password: <input type="password" ng-model="credentials.password"><br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<br/>

<i ng-show="message">{{message}}</i>
```

---

`auth.js`:

```js
var auth = angular.module("Test.auth", ["ngRoute"]);

auth.factory("AuthInterceptor", function($q, $location, UserInfo) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      if (config.url.indexOf("/api/") === 0) {
        config.headers["AJAX"] = true; // => Then server won't include WWW-Authenticate header in response and browser auth popup can be avoided
        if (!config.headers.Authorization) config.headers["ACCESS-TOKEN"] = UserInfo.accessToken();
      }
      return config;
    },
    responseError: function(response) {
      if ($location.path() !== "/login") {
        console.log("responseError - request failed with 401, go to /login");
        UserInfo.forget();
        $location.path("/login");
      }
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}).config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
});

auth.service("Auth", function($rootScope, $location, $http, UserInfo) {
  this.logIn = function(credentials) {
    $http.get("/api/v1/auth/login", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
        }
      })
      .success(function(principal) {
        UserInfo.create(principal);
        console.log("Logged in - go to /");
        $location.path("/");
      })
      .error(function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("logInFailed");
      });
  };
});

auth.service("UserInfo", function($window) {
  this.init = function() {
    if (!$window.sessionStorage["userInfo"]) this.forget();
    else this.userInfo = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage["userInfo"]);
  };
  this.create = function(principal) {
    this.userInfo = {
      userName: principal.userName,
      accessToken: principal.accessToken
    };
    $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(this.userInfo);
  };
  this.forget = function() {
    this.userInfo = null;
    $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = null;
  };
  this.accessToken = function() {
    return this.userInfo === null ? null : this.userInfo.accessToken;
  };
});

auth.controller("AuthCtrl", function($scope, Auth) {
  $scope.logIn = Auth.logIn;

  $scope.$on("logInFailed", function() {
    $scope.message = "Please provide valid credentials.";
  });
});
```

---

`hello.html`:

```html
<div>{{hello}}</div>
```

---

`hello.js`:

```js
var hello = angular.module("HelloApp", ["ngRoute", "Test.auth"]);

hello.run(function(UserInfo) {
  UserInfo.init();
});

hello.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/login", {
      templateUrl: "/test/auth.html",
      controller: "AuthCtrl"
    })
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "/test/hello.html",
      controller: "HelloCtrl",
      resolve: {
        hello: function(Hello) {
          console.log("resolve.hello");
          return Hello.promise;
        }
      }
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    });
});

hello.service("Hello", function($http) {
  this.promise = $http.get("/api/v1/utils/hello")
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("Fetched '" + response.data + "'");
      return response.data;
    });
});

hello.controller("HelloCtrl", function($scope, hello) {
  $scope.hello = hello;
});
```

Comment: Do you see this log: `console.log("Logged in - go to /");`

Comment: Yup. I have added a screen shot of the console to the question.

Comment: `console.log($location.path())` before this line ` if ($location.path() !== "/login") ` and let me know what happens?

Comment: A line with / is then showing up between the red line and the responseError line in the console.

Comment: I think the problem is that the promise is already in the rejected state and it is not being reevaluated... maybe it is just not possible to mix promise stuff with auth interception the way I do it?

Comment: I think you're right!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138829/discussion-between-jmmontero-and-stine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that `Promise` can be evaluated only once and this is by design. The obvious workaround is to change your `promise` property to a function that would return a new `Promise` every time it is called. So you can do something like:

```js
hello.service("Hello", function ($http) {
    this.promiseBuilder = function () {
        return $http.post("/api/v1/utils/hello")
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("Fetched '" + response.data + "'");
                return response.data;
            });
    };
});
```

and in the configuration:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/test/hello.html",
            controller: "HelloCtrl",
            resolve: {
                hello: function (Hello) {
                    console.log("resolve.hello");
                    return Hello.promiseBuilder();
                }
            }
        })
```

Or if you for some reason rely on the fact that `hello` service has this promise as a property, you can make `promiseBuilder` a bit more sofisticated like this:

```js
hello.service("Hello", function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    this.promiseBuilder = function () {
        self.promise = $http.post("/api/v1/utils/hello")
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("Fetched '" + response.data + "'");
                return response.data;
            });
        return self.promise;
    };
});
```

**Cached promise** (don't do it unless you have to)

There is no universal way to know if the given promise was resolved, rejected or is pending in a synchronous way. Some promise implemenations provides explicit methods for that (such as [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/)), most (including Angular) doesn't. However if you create the promise, you can always add such a feature to it using code like this:

```js
hello.service("Hello", function ($http) {
    var self = this;

    this.promiseBuilderWithCache = function () {
        if((self.promise == undefined) || !self.promiseSucceed) {
            self.promise = $http.post("/api/v1/utils/hello")
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("Fetched '" + response.data + "'");
                    return response.data;
                });
            self.promiseSucceed = false;
            self.promise.then(function () {
                self.promiseSucceed = true;
            }, function () {
                //ignore failure
            });
        }
        return self.promise;
    };
});
```

Alternatively you can add your property to the promise object itself but then beware of possible name conflicts with other code.

Note that I still strongly believe that you ***should not*** do it that way unless you have some very good reason for it.

Comment: I see! Thanks. But will there then maybe be a way to know if a promise has already been resolved? And only generate a new promise in case none has yet been resolved? :)

Comment: @Stine, you can add a bit of logic to `promiseBuilder` to re-create `promise` only if current is failed, but I don't think such custom caching is actually a good idea. I think in a typical case strategy of create new promise every time and let the browser handle all the caching according to server's instructions is much better. Let me know if you still want an example of how to add such logic to `promiseBuilder`

Comment: If you don't mind I would find it very interesting to see how it can be decided whether a promise has been resolved, thanks. I think it sounds very clever to leave the cashing up to the browser and server though...

Comment: @Stine, see my update regarding Cached promise but beware that this is most probably a bad solution

Answer (score -1):

This is what I think is happening! The following code:

```
if ($location.path() !== "/login") {
 console.log("responseError - request failed with 401, go to /login");
 UserInfo.forget();
 $location.path("/login");
}
return $q.reject(response);
```

Is rejecting the when the `$location.path()` equals to `"\"`

You need to resolve the promise if the location path is `"\"`

Comment: If I end up in `responseError` for path `/`, the promise should not be resolved as far as I understand...

Comment: another thing is that `hello.promise` is undefined!

Comment: "hello.promise" is just a string I log to the console to know if the hello method inside resolve is called. Don't understand what you mean by it being undefined?